# How do I set NSExtensionActivationRule predicates?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-extensions

Even [people far smarter than I am](http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/97658880154/what-we-learned-building-the-tumblr-ios-share) find the syntax for `NSExtensionActivationRule` arcane, but even a fool like me should be able to copy/paste examples, no? Unfortunately I can't even get [Apple's examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8) to work. The host app for my action extension crashes when you hit the share sheet button (stack trace below).

You should be able to just set `NSExtensionActivationRule` as a string, right? It works fine when I set it to `TRUEPREDICATE` for debugging purposes. But if I take this simple example from Apple (slightly modified for `public.image`) and paste it in, I get a crash:

```
{extensionItems = ({
    attachments = ({
        registeredTypeIdentifiers = (
            "public.image"
        );
    });
})}
```

I've tried the `SUBQUERY` thing too:

```
SUBQUERY($extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, 
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers 
    UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image").@count >= 1
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid this altogether by just using `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount` but as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218627/ios-appextension-how-can-i-combine-nsextensionactivationrule-and-nspredicate) found, it doesn't seem to get activated for jpgs.

Anyway, that stack trace as promised:

```
2015-02-21 23:28:08.644 MobileSlideShow[56997:2414043] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x4c985f4> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x4c9883c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
2015-02-21 23:28:08.651 MobileSlideShow[56997:2413473] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:]: index set cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x04060686 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03b35a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03f84ffe -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:] + 654
    3   UIKit                               0x01d71d78 _UIApplicationExtensionDiscoveryGetPostprocessedExtensions + 350
    4   UIKit                               0x01d718e3 -[_UIActivityApplicationExtensionDiscovery activitiesMatchingInputItems:error:updateBlock:] + 1237
    5   UIKit                               0x01c342f2 -[UIActivityViewController _availableActivitiesForItems:applicationExtensionActivities:] + 594
    6   UIKit                               0x01c3409b -[UIActivityViewController _availableActivitiesForItems:] + 48
    7   UIKit                               0x01c3519a -[UIActivityViewController _availableActivities] + 57
    8   UIKit                               0x01c39552 -[UIActivityViewController activityGroupViewController:availableActivitiesInCategory:] + 65
    9   UIKit                               0x0195c47f -[UIActivityGroupViewController collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 251
    10  UIKit                               0x01b8d94d -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 591
    11  UIKit                               0x01baced4 -[UICollectionView _userSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 191
    12  UIKit                               0x01bad0c8 -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 492
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03b4b7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    14  UIKit                               0x0164f714 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    15  UIKit                               0x0164f784 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03b4b7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    17  UIKit                               0x0164f714 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    18  UIKit                               0x0164f784 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    19  UIKit                               0x014e714a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    20  UIKit                               0x014e7c24 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 790
    21  UIKit                               0x014a5d81 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    22  UIKit                               0x014b613b _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21263
    23  UIKit                               0x01489599 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x03f820ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x03f77c0d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x03f77168 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x03f76aeb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x03f7691b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x0089e2c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x0089e106 GSEventRun + 104
    31  UIKit                               0x0148d366 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    32  MobileSlideShow                     0x00092724 MobileSlideShow + 63268
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x049dcac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: "You should be able to just set `NSExtensionActivationRule` as a string, right?" No, according to multiple mentions in the documentation, `NSExtensionActivationRule` must be a dictionary. And the example you're pasting is for an app extension item's `attachments` property, not for `NSExtensionActivationRule` in your info.plist.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was confused by this I guess: "If you need to do more complex or more specific filtering, such as distinguishing between public.url and public.image, you can create a predicate statement. Then, use the bare string that represents the predicate as the value of the NSExtensionActivationRule key," missing or misunderstanding "key".

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you might be able to use a predicate string (those are the ones that begin with `SUBQUERY`) as the value for `NSExtensionActivationRule`. (I've never needed to do it that way.) But the string you're currently using is definitely the wrong one.

Comment: Do you get an identical crash when you use the `SUBQUERY` syntax?

Comment: Yes, I do. But in the meantime I tried using  NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount again and now it's picking up public.jpeg as I expected it to in the first place. So... I'm going insane apparently. But I seem to be ok for now. Thanks very much.

Comment: If the app crashes using the exact `SUBQUERY` syntax from the documentation, please submit a radar. At the very least they should update their docs. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how it should look like and works fine for me, just try:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
            $extensionItem.attachments,
            $attachment,
            (
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg-2000"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.compuserve.gif"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.bmp"
            )
            ).@count == 1
            ).@count == 1
        </string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this was basically EXACTLY what I needed. I just needed to change the two @counts to be like this, because mine handles multiple: `).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
            ).@count > 0`

Comment: This worked great for me thank you! I just had to change the `<string>com.apple.ui-services</string>` to `<string>com.apple.share-services</string>`

Comment: Doesn't work. Error still emits. Can't upload to AppStore.

Answer (score 3):

I used below subquery for NSExtensionActivationRule to retrieve the public url, vcard, plain text from my Action Extension.

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>
            SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems, $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
            $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment,
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.vcard" || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text" || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
            ).@count >= 1
            ).@count > 0
        </string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
</dict>
```