# NSExtensionActivationRule for iOS app extension that can share everything

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I implemented a Share-Extension that works find with all sorts of things that you want to share. So I want my user to be able to share URLs, Text, Images, Videos, Any other files and even combinations of that (like from the notes app with text and a scribble).

Everything worked fine cause I didn't know about the `NSExtensionActivationRule` and by default it was set to `TRUEPREDICATE`. But as the compiler warns me, that that is not allowed, I need to change that.

I tried setting it to all kinds of combinations of values that might go there (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW10), but I just can't figure out what I need to put there, to just accept everything. Like f.e. the Slack extension...
Do I need a subquery? If so, does anybody have the "Take everything"-Subquery handy?

The `NSExtensionActivationUsesStrictMatching` set to `2` also doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this post [iOS AppExtension : How can I Combine NSExtensionActivationRule and NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218627/ios-appextension-how-can-i-combine-nsextensionactivationrule-and-nspredicate)

Combining Subquery with keys to a UTI NSExtensionActivationRule:

- NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount to "public.file-url"
- NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount to "public.movie"
- NSExtensionActivationSupportsText to "public.text"
- NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount to "public.url"

Comment: What about using just `public.data` in predicate instead of having specific content types?