# Share attachment from mail into application and save into document directory

Tags: ios, email-attachments, nsdocumentdirectory, ios8-share-extension

I refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496799/share-attachment-from-mail-app-with-share-extension-in-ios) and I am curious about it. From this answer I know that we can open attachment into application using share extension but my question is like Can we just save those attachment into document directory?

I want to save attachment of any email like gmail, outlook, ymail etc. Can we save it? Can we get all data of that attachment using share extension?

Thank you for helping me.

I appreciate any help to me.

Comment: You do not need to use a share extension for users to be able to send email attachments to your app.

Comment: so how can I save those attachments of email to my application's document direcotry? @rmaddy

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/supporting-open-in-menu-item-in-my-app-for-ios-mail-and-safari

Comment: Thank you. @rmaddy So I need to just give UTI types into plist file as i desired.